# need improvement in this method

Tags: oop, switch-statement, xcode5

here is the scene, i want to use `switch` method in this code if someone knows, will be appreciated 
there is not a big logic but someone may also describe how it will work in switch statement

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }


        if (indexPath.section == 0)

        {

        Preface *preface_access = [preface objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = preface_access.preface_title;



        }

        else if (indexPath.section == 1)

        {
            Chapters * chapter_access = [chapters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = chapter_access.chapter_title;

        }


        else
        {
            Index * index_access = [index objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = index_access.index_title;    
        }

        return cell;
    }
```

thanks in advance

i tried this one instead the above

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }


    switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        {

            Preface *preface_access = [preface objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = preface_access.preface_title;
            break;
        }
    case 1:
        {
            Chapters * chapter_access = [chapters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = chapter_access.chapter_title;
        }

    case 2:
   {
        Index * index_access = [index objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = index_access.index_title;
   }


    return cell;
}
```

the error comes here in this method Expected ';' after the expression

in `**tableview ;**`

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this snippet (Untested though):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    switch (indexPath.section)
    {
        case 0:{
            Preface *preface_access = [preface objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = preface_access.preface_title;
            return cell;
        }
        case 1:{
            Chapters * chapter_access = [chapters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = chapter_access.chapter_title;
            return cell;
        }
        case 2:{
            Index * index_access = [index objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = index_access.index_title;
            return cell;
        }
        default:
            return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did implement this one exactly but got error in the other method i have added up in the problem statement

Comment: I can see you've a mistake in the switch case, you've not put break or return in the case 1 and case 2 statements. It is necessary either to break or return in each case, otherwise both cases are treated as the same one.

Comment: I have added the break statements and now it is giving still the same

Comment: thanks a lot it worked. finally i missed a } parenthesis

Comment: please check my profile there is another issue related to this method so that you may help me out

Answer (score 0):

```
sel=indexPath.section;
switch(sel)

{
    case 0:
      Preface *preface_access = [preface objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      cell.textLabel.text = preface_access.preface_title;
    break;
    case 1:
      Chapters * chapter_access = [chapters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      cell.textLabel.text = chapter_access.chapter_title;
    break;
    default:
      Index * index_access = [index objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      cell.textLabel.text = index_access.index_title;    
    break;
}
```

Do you mean this?

Comment: I used (indexpath.section), but it did not work, so please explain this

Comment: I have implemented it is not doing the way it should..something is not working

Comment: Please send your switch case code and generated error

Comment: i used return cell instead of break statement in every switch case